# Does Oracle ManagedDataAccess driver for .net supports all Oracle database releases 12c 18c 19c

Tags: oracle, odp.net, oracle.manageddataaccess

I want to confirm that the latest Oracle managedDataAccess driver is supporting Oracle latest database releases.
I were not able to find any confirmation from Oracle documentation regarding this matter.

Answer (score 1):

You find it in the [System Requirements](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/odpnt/InstallSystemRequirements.html#GUID-A6405CAD-C0E9-45E0-9C38-26B7ED214479)

> Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver requires the following:
>
> - Same Windows operating system support as ODP.NET, Unmanaged Driver.
> - ODP.NET, Managed Driver is built with AnyCPU. It runs on either 32-bit or 64-bit (x64) Windows and on either 32-bit or 64-bit (x64)
>     .NET Framework.
> - Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2, 4.6.x, or 4.7.x.
> - **Access to Oracle Database 11g Release 2 or later**

So, connection to Oracle 11.2 or newer is supported